# What is the order Launch4J searches JRE?

Tags: bundle, javafx-2, java, launch4j

What is the order Launch4J searches JRE ?

I am shipping bundled JRE in DVD but it is very slow when it uses JRE from DVD. I know Launch4j has an option to make use of JRE available in the system already. What are the paths Launch4J search for JRE installation in a windows PC ? Can I give instruction to the advanced user that they have to install JRE in a particular location ?